# Video not from a URL input not playing

Tags: html, angularjs, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to input an external video to a textbox like this:

```
 <div class="col-xs-8" >
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name=""  style="width: 85%; margin-left: 15%" ng-model="URLLink" >
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
     <button class="btn btn-success pull-left"  id="PreviewURL" ng-click="showURLPreview(URLLink)">Preview</button><br><br><br>
  </div>
```

When I click the Preview Button, the Video file must play. In my html I have this code:

```
 <video ng-src="{{trustSrc(URLLink)}}" controls></video>
```

and in my controller I have this:

```
$scope.showURLPreview = function(URLLink){
 // alert(URLLink);
  document.getElementById('URLPreview').style.visibility='visible';
  $scope.trustSrc = function(URLLink) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(URLLink);
  }

}
```

I can get the URL already but the video is not playing on my page. It only displays a player but there is no video played or the time is also not running. HOw can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

You call the function directly in the video tag,

```
<video ng-src="{{showURLPreview(URLLink)}}" controls></video>
```

Comment: the video is still not playing

Comment: The video URL is the URL input from the user of my page that is the value of the textbox I have above

Comment: how do you make sure it is valid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173109/discussion-between-bleykfaust-and-sajeetharan).